# Error while running a selenium script on a linux server from GCP "chrome not reachable" and "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I'm trying to run a simple selenium script on linux. On windows working fine 100%. When put it in linux, it worked a few times but gave errors here and there. Now it's not working, giving errors "chrome not reachable" and "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"

i did some research and added --no-sandbox and 'disable shm usage' but nothing seems to work.

```
global driver
co = Options() 
co.add_argument("--log-level=3")    
co.add_argument('headless')
co.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
co.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
co.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
co.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
co.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
co.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=co)
driver.get('https://tradingview.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
```

Also, the terminal is super slow, even typing on it is slower than normal and the code takes 2-3 mins to return an error.

Another question is, if i keep running this and it gives an error without reaching driver.quit(), do i have numerous drivers in the background that are open and i have to manually close? (which is maybe why the linux is slow?)

Comment: Try `driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=co)`

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 same error "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Stacktrace"

Comment: Then try commenting out `co.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")`, `driver.maximize_window()`